# Terraform nested conditional to mimic else-if

Tags: terraform

I would need a help with reviewing of below nested conditional where for the life of me I am not able to find a syntax error which is causing the logic to be broken. Problem is not within the logic itself although I admit that it's bit messy but within the syntax how I am connecting one conditional branch to another

```
"(${length(regexall("(?i)READ$", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0 ? 
 "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__R" : (
 ${length(regexall("(?i)READ_WRITE", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0
 "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__RW" : (
 ${length(regexall("(?i)READ_WRITE_CTRL", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0
 "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__RWC" : null))})"
```

Flow stops right away during terraform init with below errors:

This character is not used within the language.

Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template syntax.

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Below is a functional version not utilizing nested conditional:

```
"${length(regexall("(?i)READ$", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0 ? 
"_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__R" : 
"TEST"}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is quite incorrect, i corrected it below by inserting the missing elements, for this I just improved the indentation as you can see it is much simpler to find what is missing:

```
"(${
length(regexall("(?i)READ$", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0 
  ? "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__R" 
  : "(${
    length(regexall("(?i)READ_WRITE", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0 
      ? "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__RW" 
      : "(${
          length(regexall("(?i)READ_WRITE_CTRL", "${trimspace(each.value.access_type)}" )) > 0 
            ? "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__RWC" 
            : null
        })"
    })"
})"
```

[image]

As you can see it was quite a thing that makes me wonder if fixing it might still not work.

Comment: Ohh...it seems like I have missed more than one bit of mandatory syntax. Your adjustments fixed the flow and now this logic correctly assigns name of technical role (output of each branch) based on the input, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't directly answering your question, but here is another possible way to express this mapping rule using a lookup table and a single regular expression lookup, which you might find easier to maintain:

```
locals {
  access_type_suffixes = tomap({
    "READ"            = "R"
    "READ_WRITE"      = "RW"
    "READ_WRITE_CTRL" = "RWC"
  })

  access_rule_types = tomap({
    for k, v in WHATEVER_YOUR_FOR_EACH_CURRENTLY_REFERS_TO :
    k => regex("(?i)(?:READ(?:_WRITE(?:_CTRL)?)?)?", v.access_type)
  })
}

resource "example" "example" {
  for_each = WHATEVER_YOUR_FOR_EACH_CURRENTLY_REFERS_TO

  this_thing = "_AR_${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[0]}", 9, -1)}__${substr("${split(",", trimspace(each.value.parameter_names))[1]}", 7, -1)}__${local.access_rule_suffixes[local.access_rule_types[each.key]]}"
}
```

The idea here is to use the one regex pattern to match the longest possible valid prefix of the `READ_WRITE_CTRL` string in each of your access types and gather those all up into a map in `local.access_rule_types`. The other local value `local.access_type_suffixes` then acts as a mapping table from long name to short suffix, so you then only need to write out this complex string template expression once, with a reference to the appropriate elements of those two maps.